# Cannot update custom field description

Tags: jira

I'm using JIRA 4.1.2. I have a page layout created using Jelly, but now that the app is in production I need to manually change a field description (can't run the script again).

The documentation says to go to Field Configurations -> Configure -> Edit, enter the text and hit update. I do that but nothing changes. HOWEVER, for a field that was created outside of Jelly, using the standard JIRA UI, an update works.

What gives? *None* of my jelly-created fields will update.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I should add that the "Edit Field Description" page shows my updated changes - the update just isn't reflected on the page itself (when viewing in Edit or Create mode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check which field configuration is being used for a specific issue.

Comment: Got it! I was totally changing the wrong configuration. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Is there any reason why changing the description in the database didn't work?